# Use OAuth and ASP.Net Identity in AWS API Gateway's Custom Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, authorization, aws-api-gateway

I have an existing Web API that I migrated to AWS using API Gateway and Lambda functions. However, I'm wondering how I can make use of AWS API Gateway's custom authorizer feature. My existing authorization framework is OAuth and I used ASP.Net Identity for user management. I generate bearer tokens and used the 'Authorized' attribute in my API Controllers for security. How can I do the same in AWS API gateway since I cannot change my framework cause I already have existing users. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, check out the docs for custom authorizers: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html

You should be able to write the Lambda function to replicate the authorization logic used in your existing service. Then think about how you want to model permissions in terms of an IAM policy (which is the output of the authorizer). If you want simple allow|deny then you can return an IAM policy from the authorizer that says Allow `*` or Deny `*`. Or you can add fine grained permissions if you want.